# How to use Azure DevOps REST API to Update File?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-repos

I'm trying to Update a `test.json` file hosted on a Azure DevOps Repo. I'm using a Logic App. Having trouble identifying the order of operations from the documentation.

**I think I need to...**

1. Issue a GET HTTP request to the [`Items` endpoint:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#get-metadata)

   - `https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/myProject/_apis/git/repositories/myRepoID/items?scopePath=/data/test.json&$format=json&api-version=6.0`
   - Response:

   ```json
   {
     "count": 1,
     "value": [
       {
         "objectId": "<longGUID>",
         "gitObjectType": "blob",
         "commitId": "<longGUID>",
         "path": "/data/test.json",
         "url": "https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/longGUID/_apis/git/repositories/myRepoID/items?path=%2Fdata%2Ftest.json&versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
2. Use the `objectId` in the response to issue a POST HTTP request to the [`Pushes` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#add-a-binary-file)

   - Body:

```json
{
  "refUpdates": [
    {
      "name": "refs/heads/main",
      "oldObjectId": "<longGuid from previous response>"
    }
  ],
  "commits": [
    {
      "changes": [
        {
          "changeType": "edit",
          "item": {
            "path": "/data/test.json"
          },
          "newContent": {
            "content": "CHECK CHECK!",
            "contentType": "rawtext"
          }
        }
      ],
      "comment": "My commit message"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Error:**

- Status 409 Conflict

```json
{
  "$id": "1",
  "innerException": null,
  "message": "TF401028: The reference 'refs/heads/main' has already been updated by another client, so you cannot update it. Please try again.",
  "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server.GitReferenceStaleException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server",
  "typeKey": "GitReferenceStaleException",
  "errorCode": 0,
  "eventId": 3000
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Am I correct on the order of operations?
2. How do I overcome this issue?

**FIX:** (Thank you @Leo_Liu-MSFT)

1. GET request to `https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/myProject/_apis/git/repositories/repoID/commits?searchCriteria.$top=1&searchCriteria.itemVersion.version=main&api-version=6.0`
2. POST request to `https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/myProject/_apis/git/repositories/repoID/pushes`

- Body:

```json
{
  "commits": [
    {
      "changes": [
        {
          "changeType": "edit",
          "item": {
            "path": "<Your File To Update>"
          },
          "newContent": {
            "content": "CHECK CHECK!",
            "contentType": "rawtext"
          }
        }
      ],
      "comment": "<YOUR COMMIT MSG>"
    }
  ],
  "refUpdates": [
    {
      "name": "refs/heads/main",
      "oldObjectId": "<commitId from previous response>"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to use Azure DevOps REST API to Update File?

The `oldObjectId` in the request body is not the value of the `objectId`.

It should be the the **latest commit SHA for the branch `main`**.

- Go to the code page > Files
- Choose a repository and branch
- Select the root level (repository name) > History
- Click … of the first commit > Copy full SHA

And the value should be create a new branch `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` when used to create a new branch.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Which REST API endpoint will give me `latest commit SHA for the branch main.`? I need to automate this rather than manually determine it.

Comment: @SeaDude, Using the REST API commit on a branch: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#on-a-branch

Comment: @Leo_Liu-MSFT, I successfully called the `get-commits on-a-branch`. There is no `sha` key in the response. Does the first `commitId` in the response = "`latest commit SHA for the branch main`"?

Comment: @SeaDude, You can try to compare it with UI. I am not test it, but is should be correct. If it not correct, please let me know, I'll take the time to check it out

Comment: @Leo_Liu-MSFT, thank you. The first `commitID` = SHA. I was able to commit an Update file.