# Is it possible to update a file in azure devops repository using power automate?

Tags: azure-devops, automation, powerapps, power-automate

I can't find any connector in power automate to update a file in azure devops repository.

I am trying to automate the process of checkin our deployment sheet in azure devops repository. My flow is triggered when the custom work item type is closed. An adaptive card is sent to teams where the user can update the logs. Then I want to automatically update the log sheet present in azure devops. Prior to this we used to update the sheet in excel and again commit it from visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

For operations which are not supported by the default connector you could always look into using the Azure DevOps REST API service in combination with an Send an HTTP request to Azure DevOps action.

I would look into using for example the Pushes - Create method:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP

Have a look at this StackOverflow thread, that might be useful as well:
[How to use Azure DevOps REST API to Update File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71302608/how-to-use-azure-devops-rest-api-to-update-file)